# PayPal決済ページの言語はどう設定しますか

Tags: paypal

PayPal決済ページの言語はどう設定しますか。
アカウントで設定しますか、それともAPIなどで設定しますか。

Comment: http://note.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/detail/n384939

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PayPal支払画面の表示言語は、PayPalサーバーで各要素を合わせて自動的に判断され、適当な言語を表示しています。

①ブラウザの言語設定。
②ブラウザのCookieに、PayPal関連のCookie。
　（一度ログインしたユーザーでは、そのユーザーの言語設定がCookieに残り、
   次回ではCookie  により、この言語で表示されます。）
③ExpressCheckoutを使う場合：LOCALECODEパラメータ。Website Payments Standardを使う場合：lcパラメータ。
④配送先国のパラメータ。ExpressCheckoutを使う場合：PAYMENTREQUEST_n_SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODEパラメータ。Website Payments Standardを使う場合：countryパラメータ。

マーチャント側で制御できるのは③です。③のパラメータの詳細は下記のURLを参考してください：
LOCALECODEパラメータ（エクスプレスチェックをご利用の場合）：「LOCALECODE」を検索する
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/

lcパラメータ（ウェブペイメントスタンダードをご利用の場合）：「lc」を検索する
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#id08A6HI0709B

例えば、日本語表示にしたい場合、上記パラメータが「JP」を指定指定してください、英語表示にしたい場合、上記パラメータが「US」を指定指定してください。

PayPalアカウントでボタンを作成してウェブサイトに貼り付けているマーチャントでは、
lcパラメータを追加する方法はボタン編集ページで、ステップ3の「高度な変数を追加する」のところで、下記のような内容を追加します：
lc=JP

また、サードパーティーのショッピングカートを使用している場合では、ショッピングカートのソースコードを修正して上記のパラメータの値を変更する必要があるかと思います。
修正方法はショッピングカート問い合わせてください。

PayPalではテクニカルサポートの部署がありますので、何かPayPal実装関連の質問や技術的な質問がありましたら、下記URLで記事を検索してみてください。
https://jp.paypal-techsupport.com/
上記URLの一番下の「お問い合わせ」リンクをクリックしてまたは下記URLをアクセスして質問を送信してください。
https://jp.paypal-techsupport.com/app/ask